# Can I put a window function inside a case statement to reference that case statement?

Tags: sql, case, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have a table with subscriptions. It has the company id, the start of the subscription and the end of the subscription. I added the rank with a window function.

This is what the data looks like -

```
company_id  datestart   dateend rank
abc         1/1/17      1/5/17  1
aab         2/1/17      2/5/17  1
abb         1/15/17     1/30/17 1
abb         2/5/17      2/20/17 2
abb         5/1/17      5/15/17 3
abe         3/1/17      3/5/17  1
aad         2/1/17      3/1/17  1
aad         7/1/17      7/28/17 2
aad         8/15/17     8/17/17 3
aad         8/18/17     9/1/17  4
```

I want to group them into periods.

I want to have a rule that says-

If the company_id is the same and the next subscription starts within 30 days of the last subscription, then they are part of the same group. 
If the company_id is the same and the next subscription starts after 30 days of the last subscription, then make it +1 period.

This is what I want the data to look like -

```
company_id  datestart   dateend rank    period
abc         1/1/17      1/5/17  1       1
aab         2/1/17      2/5/17  1       1
abb         1/15/17     1/30/17 1       1
abb         2/5/17      2/20/17 2       1
abb         5/1/17      5/15/17 3       2
abe         3/1/17      3/5/17  1       1
aad         2/1/17      3/1/17  1       1
aad         7/1/17      7/28/17 2       2
aad         8/15/17     8/17/17 3       2
aad         1/1/18      1/5/18  4       3
```

Here's what I've tried and where I'm stuck -

```
with subscriptions_cte as 
(SELECT company_id, datestart, dateend,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY datestart) AS rank,
lag(datestart, 1) over (partition by company_id order by datestart asc) as prior_datestart,
lag(dateend, 1) over (partition by company_id order by datestart asc) as prior_dateend,
datediff(days, datestart, dateend) as subscription_length,
FROM subscriptions)

SELECT companyid, rank, datestart, dateend,
CASE WHEN rank = 1 then 1 
WHEN datediff(days, prior_dateend, datestart) < 30 THEN 
MAX(evaluation_period over (partition by companyid)
ELSE (MAX(evaluation_period) over (partition by companyid)) + 1  
END as evaluation_period
FROM subscriptions_cte
```

I'm stuck because I can't reference evaluation_period in the case statement for evaluation_period. I need to be able to make the value the next period.  Let me know if there is more info I can include.

Misc: This is on redshift with postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select s.*,
       sum(case when prev_date_end >= date_start - interval '30 day' then 0 else 1 end ) over (partition by company_id order by rank) as period
from (select s.*, lag(date_end) over (partition by company_id order by rank) as prev_date_end
      from subscriptions s
     ) s
```